# Connecting RTK Query API with redux reducer and selector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I think I'm missing something with regards to Redux and RTK Query tools.  I'm also using RTK Query OpenAPI codegen for this.

Right now I have an API that looks like this ->

```
export const api = generatedApi.enhanceEndpoints({
  endpoints: {
    getMaterials: {
      transformResponse: response => normalize(response),
    },
  },
})
```

This gives me back normalized data fine in my component:

```
const Materials = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetMaterialsQuery()

  /*
    Cool this gives me data back like:
    {
      [id]: {
        id,
        prop1: 'blah',
        prop2: 'blah2'
      }
    }
  */

  console.log(data)

  // but now I want to structure this data differently using selector

  const newDataStructure = useSelector(addSomeMetaDataAndStructureDifferentlySelector)

  return <MyComponent structuredData={newDataStructure} />
}
```

But when I look at state in that selector it looks like:

[image: data snippet]

When in the selector I really want to use something like ->

```
const addSomeMetaDataAndStructureDifferentlySelector = state => 
    // create new data structure from state.materials.byId that I will pass to `MyComponent`
```

My store looks like this right now ->

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { api } from 'gen/rtk-openapi'
// import materialsReducer from 'state/materials/materialsSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)

export default store
```

So do I need to pass the `data` directly from `useGetMaterialsQuery` into a function and just transform it?

Or can I somehow create a new reducer slice that somehow initializes with the data correctly so that I can access `state.materials.byId` in a selector?

Or am I fundamentally missing something here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You missed an important bit: [RTK-Query is not a normalized cache](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/comparison#no-normalized-or-deduplicated-cache), but a Document cache.

It caches your endpoints and each request to those, using the request arguments as cache keys. Each of those responses is treated as a "document" and cached separately.

That might seem like a drawback, but doing a real "normalized" cache is almost impossible as a generic library, especially for something ambiguous as REST apis. Even for GraphQL it is a very hard problem and even solutions specialized on GraphQL (like apollo) have lots of problems and end up with lots of hand-written code to handle cases like additions/removals from collections.

So in the end, you are left with two choices: write your own normalized caching solution by hand, explicitly geared towards your data structures or use a document cache.

In most situations, a document cache is just enough. And that's where RTK-Query comes in and tries to give you as many tools as possible to keep data "in sync" between your documents: [automated refetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching) and where you want to avoid that the option to do [manual optimistic updates](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/optimistic-updates) to manipulate specific cache entries.

Generally, I would recommend against copying that data over to hand-written slices. You will lose a lot of benefits of RTK-Query that way, for example subscription tracking and automatic cache cleanup after no more components use a value after 60 seconds.
It might sound uncommon after using Redux with hand-written slices for a while, but it works very well in most situations - with a lot less code.

As for how to use it: Generally, you just call your `useGetMaterialsQuery()` in all components that need the materials and just filter out what you need in your component, or use the `selectFromResult` option to just select what you really need.

Comment: how is selectFromResult used?

Comment: `const result = useGetMaterialsQuery(undefined, { selectFromResult: result => ({ ...result, data: result.data.foo.bar }) })`

Comment: This answer makes sense to me but I’m still struggling to figure out where in rtk-query you store changes to the document cache that you need for your components. I know copying over the cache into another slice is frowned upon, so should I create more custom hooks to add/filter/update values (client-side only nothing going back to the server) or should I place any business-logic adjustments to my server response in somewhere like `transformResponse`? For example, if I wanted to combine two fields on an object response into a new key value, where does that happen?

Comment: @aboutaaron if everywhere you consume that endpoint, you consume it in the same form, then in `transformResponse`. If one component wants only a part of a response, I would use `selectFromResult` and if it needs to do a data transformation on top of that, I'd just `useMemo`.

Comment: @phry do you suggest using `useFooQuery(...)` over `api.endpoints.foo.select('cache-key')` with `useSelector`?

Comment: @onosendi In almost all cases, if you can use hooks, yes.